# Simple js.erb in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got the 'destroy.js.erb' file with the following content:

```
alert(<%=j @menu.id %>);
```

But this code doesn't work; I've got the exception about syntax error. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the error stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `escape_javascript` (`j`) tries to call `gsub` from your `@menu.id`

[escape_javascript](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb#L25-L34):

```
def escape_javascript(javascript)
  if javascript
    result = javascript.gsub(/(\|<\/|\r\n|\342\200\250|\342\200\251|[\n\r"'])/) {|match| JS_ESCAPE_MAP[match] }
    javascript.html_safe? ? result.html_safe : result
  else
    ''
  end
end
```

If you really want to use `escape_javascript`:

```
alert(<%=j @menu.id.to_s %>);
```

otherwise (without `escape_javascript`):

```
alert(<%= @menu.id %>);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the `j` helper if you're just outputting an integer

```
alert(<%= @menu.id %>);
```

If you have a string, the `j` helper is more applicable. If you want to coerce your id into a string, use `to_s`

```
alert("<%=j @menu.id.to_s %>");
```